# Verify: Allen-Cahn equation is a gradient system in $L^2$ (struggling with the initial conditions)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Consider the Allen-Cahn equation
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+f(u), x\in\mathbb{R}\qquad (*)
$$
with $f(u)=u(1-u^2)$ and initial condition $u(0,x)=u_0(x)\in\text{BC}^0(\mathbb{R})$, the bounded uniformly continuous functions on the real line.

Now, it is said that $(*)$ is a gradient system in $L^2$ with respect to the energy
$$
V(u):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\frac{1}{2}u_x^2+F(u))\, dx, 
$$
where $F(s)=\int_0^sf(s)$.

---

I would like to verify that.

My computations for the first variation  $\delta V(u)$ give that
$$
\langle \delta V(u),v\rangle_{L^2}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}u_xv_x+F'(u)v\, dx
$$

Now, I think, I have to integrate by parts, i.e.
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}u_xv_x\, dx= [u_xv]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-\int_{\mathbb{R}}u_{xx}v\, dx.
$$

Is it possible to use now $u_0(x)\in\text{BC}^0(\mathbb{R})$ to show that on the right hand side for the first summand we have
$$
[u_xv]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}=0?
$$

If yes, I get
$$
\langle \delta V(u),v\rangle_{L^2}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}u_xv_x+F'(u)v\, dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(-u_{xx}+F'(u))v\, dx=\langle -u_{xx}+F'(u),v\rangle_{L^2},
$$
hence $\delta V(u)=-u_{xx}+F'(u)$.

Moreover, what is $F'(u)$? Is this $F'(u)=f(u)$ by fundamental theorem of calculus?

Please help me. :)

Answer (score 1):

1) I think that in the definition of space $BC^0(\mathbb{R})$, superscript $0$ means that functions from $BC^0(\mathbb{R})$ have to vanish on infinity, that is $u(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \pm\infty$. (Or even have to have compact supports.) 
Moreover, you know that $v \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, which implies that $v$ cannot tend to infinity as $x \to \infty$. Therefore, $[u_xv]_{-\infty}^{+\infty} = 0$, indeed.

2) Yes, $F'(u) = f(u)$ by fundamental theorem of calculus and the fact that $f(0) = 0$.